# Swagger-UI not showing up for spring-reactive app created using jhipster

Tags: java, spring, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I followed the steps from sprinddoc github and added the below

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "Amazingbabbage", version = "1.0", description = "Documentation APIs v1.0"))
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ LiquibaseProperties.class, ApplicationProperties.class })
public class AmazingbabbageApp {
```

The application starts successfully. It also services the documentation at `/v3/api-docs`

When I launch `swagger-ui.html` it gives me `whitelabel` page with 404.

I also tried adding webconfig

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.resource.WebJarsResourceResolver;

import static org.springdoc.core.Constants.CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATION;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig  implements WebFluxConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATION+"/webjars/")
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new WebJarsResourceResolver());
    }
}
```

Still there is not change. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What URL are you using to access swagger?

Comment: I am using `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html`